# jQuery input field sent to top of page fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a signin form with multiple input fields. It is going onto an ipad and because of this I want to make the input field move to the top of the screen after you click it so that the fields don't get blocked by the keyboard. I am using the following code.

```
$('#signinform input').on('focus', function() {
document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top; });
```

This works great but it shoots the field to the very top, is there a way to stop it 10 px before so that I can still see the title for the specific input field? Do I need to put a value into the offset part of the jQuery?

[What is happening (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arBbF.png)

[What I want to happen (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfRV8.png)

Thank you

Comment: document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top - 40px;

Comment: @Rijin that didn't work, console said it was an "unexpected identifier"

Comment: U don't include the px, thanks for the fast answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subtracting 30px from the offset. You can do math calculations right on that function.

`document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top - 30 ;`

Answer (score 0):

subtract few pixels from top when scrolled.

document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top - [your desired px]